# React-redux state is update, but i does not affect view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am learning React Redux by trying to make a todo app.
My state is like this

```
[
  {
    taskName:"ABS",
    status: true
  },
  {
    taskName:"XYZ",
    status: false
  }
]
```

Basically, each task is an object. I want to toggle the status of specific task every time I press a button (it changes color between red and green), so I design my reducer as follow:

Attemp 1:

```
var stateClone = [...state];
stateClone[action.index].status = !stateClone[action.index].status;
return stateClone;
```

Attemp 2:

```
var cloneTask = {...state[action.index]}
cloneTask.status = !cloneTask.status;
state[action.index] = cloneTask
localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(state));
return [...state];
```

As my understanding, both are pure function. Both return the correct state, however only attemp 2 updated the view successfully, the attemp 1 did update state but it didnt update view correctly.

Someone help me. Thanks!

**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TaskItem from './TaskItem';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
class TaskList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filterName: '',
            filterStatus: -1
        };
    }
    onChange = (event)=>{
        var target = event.target;
        var name = target.name;
        var value = target.value;
        console.log(name)
        this.props.onFilter(name==='filterName'?value:this.state.filterName, 
                            name==='filterStatus'?value:this.state.filterStatus);
        this.setState({
            [name]:value
        });
    }
    render() {
        // console.log(this.props);
        var { tasks } = this.props;
        var { filterName, filterStatus } = this.state;
        var elemTask = tasks.map((item, index)=>{
            return <TaskItem 
                        key={index+1} 
                        item={item} 
                        index={index} 
                        deleteTask={this.props.deleteTask}
                        editTask = {this.props.editTask}
                    />
        }); 
        return (
            <table className="table table-bordered table-hover mt-15">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th className="text-center">STT</th>
                        <th className="text-center">Task</th>
                        <th className="text-center">Status</th>
                        <th className="text-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input 
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                name="filterName"
                                value={filterName}
                                onChange={this.onChange}
                            />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="filterStatus" 
                                    value={filterStatus} 
                                    className="form-control"
                                    onChange={this.onChange}>
                                <option value={-1}>All</option>
                                <option value={0}>OnHold</option>
                                <option value={1}>Active</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    {elemTask}
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        tasks: state.tasks
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TaskList);
```

**

**My react file that should get the state from store**

```js
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
var initialState = data? data: [];

var myReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
 switch(action.type){
  case types.LIST_ALL:
   return state;

  case types.ADD_TASK:
   var newTask = {
    id: Math.random(),
    name: action.task.name ,
    status: action.task.status==='true'
   }
   state.push(newTask);
   localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(state));
   return [...state];

  case types.UPDATE_STATUS:
   // var stateClone = [...state];
   // stateClone[action.index].status = !stateClone[action.index].status;
   // console.log(stateClone);
   // return stateClone;
   
   var cloneTask = {...state[action.index]}
   cloneTask.status = !cloneTask.status;
   state[action.index] = cloneTask
   localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(state));
   console.log(state);
   return [...state];
  default: return state
 }
};

export default myReducer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you *mutate* the state.

In the first, you copy the objects and then change one of them; React sees the same objects and thinks nothing has changed.

In the second, you make a new object but place it in the existing array. React sees still the same array and thinks nothing has changed.

You need to return a new array, with a new object for the one that has changed.

One way to do that is to basically combine your two tries:

```
var stateClone = [...state];
var cloneTask = {...state[action.index]};
cloneTask.status = !cloneTask.status;
stateClone[action.index] = cloneTask;
return stateClone;
```

Should work.

Comment: But i log the state and I see that it updated every time I click the button. I map the state to props and i also see it update everytime i click the button.

Comment: The contents change, but React uses an optimization where it first looks at the reference. If it's still the same object, it's assumed not to have changed.